# What does ? operator mean in React when used like this:

Tags: typescript

Working with React code, I see this `?` used a lot but I don't know what it means.

Like, in the context below:

```
export const useIsACGManagerByTransaction = (data?: AgreementRowData[]): boolean => {

...

...

};
```

What does the `?` question mark operator do here for the `data` parameter?

Comment: The parameter is optional, but it's TypeScript-y, not JS-y.